# coldbox rc var not showing up

Tags: coldfusion, coldbox

ColdBox Variable

handlers/home.cfc

```
<cffunction name="index" output="false" hint="index">
    <cfargument name="event">
    <cfset rc.Test = 'This is a test 123.' />
    <cfset event.setView("home/index")>
</cffunction>
```

views/home/index.cfm

```
<cfdump var="#rc#" />
```

Why is rc.test not showing up in the dump?

Comment: Is it saying, "rc" is not defined" or is it saying "test is not defined in rc"?

Answer (score 3):

Without `rc` defined with `cfargument`, your `rc.test` will be set to `variables.rc.test` in your handler.

Do this:

```
<cffunction name="index" output="false" hint="index">
    <cfargument name="event">
    <cfargument name="rc">
    <cfargument name="prc">
    <cfset rc.Test = 'This is a test 123.' />
    <cfset event.setView("home/index")>
</cffunction>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign RC to Event.getCollection(). We do this at the top of every handler function.

```
<cffunction name="index" returntype="void" output="false">
    <cfargument name="event" required="true">
    <cfscript>
        var rc = event.getCollection();
        var prc = event.getCollection( private = true );

        // your handler code here

        Event.setView('home/index');
    </cfscript>
</cffunction>
```